# How to fix AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id' when using custom loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

In learning to do machine learning with point clouds I am porting the original [PointNet](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet) code (written in TF1) to TensorFlow2. Everything was going well until I tried porting the custom loss. I subclassed *keras.Model* to implement a custom training step as follows:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    
    def set_params(self, end_points, reg_weight=0.001):
        self.end_points = end_points
        self.reg_weight = reg_weight
        
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
     
            loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred, labels=y)
            
            classify_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            
            # Enforce the transformation as orthogonal matrix
            transform = self.end_points['transform'] # BxKxK
            K = transform.shape[1]
            mat_diff = tf.matmul(transform, tf.transpose(transform, perm=[0,2,1]))
            mat_diff -= tf.constant(np.eye(K), dtype=tf.float32)
            mat_diff_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(mat_diff) 
            

            loss = classify_loss + mat_diff_loss * self.reg_weight

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

when training, I get an error exactly at `gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)`

The error is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [15], in <cell line: 12>()
> 9 steps_per_epoch = train_count//BATCH_SIZE
> 10 validation_steps = validation_count//BATCH_SIZE
> ---> 12 history = model.fit(training_dataset,
> 13                     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, validation_data=validation_dataset, validation_steps=validation_steps,
> epochs=EPOCHS)
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf_p3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67,
> in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
> 66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> ---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 68 finally:
> 69   del filtered_tb
>
> File /tmp/**autograph_generated_file9wypl4wp.py:15, in
> outer_factory..inner_factory..tf__train_function(iterator)
> 13 try:
> 14     do_return = True
> ---> 15     retval* = ag*_.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
> 16 except:
> 17     do_return = False
>
> Input In [3], in CustomModel.train_step(self, data)
> 30 # Compute gradients
> 31 trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
> ---> 32 gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
> 34 # Update weights
> 35 self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
>
> AttributeError: in user code:
>
> ```
> File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/envs/tf_p3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> ```
>
> line 1051, in train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/envs/tf_p3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1040, in step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/envs/tf_p3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1030, in run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> File "/tmp/ipykernel_16312/3458445038.py", line 32, in train_step
> gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id'
> ```

[Here is a Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VSub1CYmGlG2vUYYdDTgNOIqmV58uSkM?usp=sharing) with the main parts, you can run all cells to reproduce the error.

I have spent several hours trying different ways to implement the custom loss without luck, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think versioning issue and please try `Keras == 2.3.1` with `tensorflow==2.2.0`.